# Create thumbnails using AWS S3 & Lambda and then load them

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm building a react webapp which allows users to upload a picture and then render the thumbnail, just like facebook chat. But I'm not sure what's the best practice to solve the uploading-resizing-generatingThumbnail time gap before I can render them.

**The workflow is like:**

1) User uploads a picture to S3, stored in bucket1

2) Lambda function invoked, getting the newly uploaded picture and do the resizing work, then store thumbnail in bucket2

3) Thumbnail rendered in browser(client-side). Here it's a bit tricky - I just hardcode the img url because it's predictable, however, it takes a while before available(generating process).

But I don't know how to let lambda notifies the browser when a thumbnail successfully generated and ready to render. In production it might be lambda tells node server first, and then node server tells the client; but in developing mode, it seems impossible as I'm running an express server on my own laptop. Should lambda do the notification in a proper way or there's other better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda cannot "notify the browser" because it is a process that was **independently triggered** and has no connection with the web page request.

One option would be to code the web page to **keep trying to download the image**. You'd need some fancy JavaScript/node code that can check whether the image was successfully downloaded and then retry if necessary.

By the way, **there are also services that can resize images on-the-fly** so you don't have to create your own thumbnails:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I end up continuously sending HTTP requests to test image link every second - at least it works.